# Showing image in Radgrid using datatable

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have an image inside the image folder; I want to show that in a RadGrid using a data table which is populated from code behind

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why use datatable to show "an" image? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Needed to display a image if a user is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Image Column");
dt.Rows.Add("<img src= ../image/image.png   />");
RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```